# Effect of the neutral current to a system when a 3-phase facility is used as unbalanced

Tags: three-phase, neutral

Normally 3 phase-systems are used for balanced loads like in 3-phase AC induction motors. I know that in a balanced star configuration the total current across the neutral is zero.

But what if each phases are loaded with different loads(unbalanced)? Obviously there will be non-zero neutral current. It seems that is the only difference between a balanced and an unbalanced 3-phase system.

Would such unbalanced use of 3-phase facility and thus a non-zero neutral current cause any kind of faults or harmonics in a system? Why?